# How do I make the return value of an ejs(Node.js) function change at every call?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I made a html(ejs) button, that whenever clicked, it communicates with a node.js file and returns a randomly picked number. The first click works and returns a random number(eg 1).
The problem is, in the next click, the button returns the same number(1) and continues to do so at all following clicks.
Please how do I make the return value of this ejs function change at every click?

The index.ejs

```
   <div style="width: 400px;height:80px;display:inline-block;">
        <div onclick="calculateResult()">
            Button           //// Button is actually a div
        </div>      
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
        alert('<%= calculateResult() %>')
   </script>
```

The app.js(node.js)

```
app.locals.calculateResult = function(){
    randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
    return randomPick
}
```

Comment: Secondary problem: don't use alert, it is an ancient function that can't do anything other than block the thread while displaying the result of a .toString() call. Use the console API for debugging, or use normal HTML with appropriate CSS to present information to your users. Also don't use `onclick`, we're not using HTML4.01 anymore, have a separate .js file (which can be EJS generated just as everything else) that you link to with `<script src="..."></script>`(no type attribute. scripts are JS _unless_ you override the type in HTML5) and query your DOM so you can addEventListener

Comment: AFAIK `ejs` is a _template_ engine: `<%= calculateResult() =%>` is actually _computed on the server_, i.e. _before sending the HTML to the client_. If you inspect your HTML in the browser, you should see a _statically written_ `alert('1')`. If you need the server to compute a value for the client, you'll need to code: 1/ an endpoint on the server that provides a random number on request; 2/ some AJAX/XmlHttpRequest logic on the client to hit that endpoint and use the received number.

Comment: You helped me understand something more with your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @stock-overflaw stated your `<%= calculateResult() %>` is being computed on the server then sent to the client compiled

That means `alert('<%= calculateResult() %>')` is always `alert('1')` no matter how many times the button is clicked after the page has been rendered

A more better approach is to reduce the stress of that computation from the server and implement it in the client side
just like this

```
       <div onclick="calculateResult()">
            Button 
        </div> 

   <script type="text/javascript" >
 const calculateResult = () =>{
    randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
   alert('randomPick')
}
  
   </script>
```

but if you still need to send a new value from the server you would have to write another route to handle that